# Min Value of $a$ where $a^x$ and $\log_a x$ have a common tangent

Tags: calculus, derivatives

The question asks me to find the minimum value of $a$, where $a > 1$, that $f(x) = a^x$ and $g(x) = \log_a x$ have a common tangent.

I solved for the derivatives of the two functions, and got 
$$f'(x) = \ln (x) * a^x $$  $$ g'(x) = \frac{1}{x*\ln(a)}$$ $$\ln (x) * a^x = \frac{1}{x*\ln(a)}$$

I also know that at the tangent, the two functions must equal each other. So 
$$a^x = \log_a x$$

But from there, I unfortunately don't know how to continue. What steps should 
I take next in finding the $a$ where the two functions have a common tangent? I did try substituting $\log_a x$ in for $a^x$ but that didn't lead me anywhere.

Comment: It is notable that
$$
a^x = \log_ax \implies a^{a^x} = x
$$

Comment: In fact, with the above we can make the following observation: if $a>1$ , then $a^x$ is increasing.  So,
$$
a^x > x \implies a^{a^x} > a^x > a^x
$$
and 
$$
a^x < x \implies a^{a^x} < a^x < x
$$
so, we can only have a solution to your equation if $a^x = x$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can consider the equation $a^x=x$ taking the logarithm on both sides we get

$\ln(a)=\frac{\ln(x)}{x}$ now define $f(x)=\frac{\ln(x)}{x}$ and use calculus. For 
$x=e$ we get the maximum values, $f(e)=\frac{1}{e}$ so we get
$$\ln(a)=\frac{1}{e}$$ or $$a=e^{1/e}$$